# MS SQL ldf file unchanged the last month

Tags: sql-server-2012

I've restored a mssql database from a backup a month ago and it seemed OK.
A month later, looking at the db physical files, I can see that the ldf has not changed since (has the same date stamp and same size), while the mdf has grown a bit and has today's date stamp. The ldf file is about 195MB, while the mdf file is about 780MB.
Is this normal? Can this affect performance? What can I do?

I'm asking this, because the database is a Umbraco one and the website has become very slow and have no idea where to start looking.
The database is on a Windows/SQL Server 2012 and Umbraco is 4.7.0. The backup came from an SQL Server 2008.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the dates are concerned, there is no need to worry. Windows will update the date when the file grows (or shrinks) in size. This might not happen for quite a while if the sizes were configured correctly. It's also usually better to have the size of the ldf lower than the mdf size.

There is a lot to uncover if you wish to get rid of the performance problems you are experimenting... and all those issues could easily fill several books. If the performance is that bad, consider asking for external help to come and do some diagnosis. Or give more info on what kind of problems you are having (time, frequency, duration, kind of wait, ...)

Comment: Thanks for that, but it's my understanding that an ldf holds the database transaction log. And the last month, there were a loot of transactions, so I find it strange that the ldf wasn't modified **at all**.

Comment: Hopefully your transaction log was saved in the meantime. If not, I agree that its size will go over the roof. But if it is backup up (as it should), it is really possible that a properly planned log file size was enough to contain the incoming changes. You can have a lot of free space in those files and windows will only change the modification date if the file is growing or shrinking.